# paginacion con laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Poseo esta clase que funciona como el controlador de bitacora de mi proyecto, me gustaria hacer una paginacion me estado guiando de donde podria ir el valor pero me arroja el siguiente error: Call to a member function paginate() on array 
No se si es necesario tener que hacer unas modificaciones para que funcione...

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
 use App\Models\ConfigsModel;
use App\Models\BitacoraModel;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class BitacoraController extends Controller
{
function buscarBitacora(Request $request){

$modelo = new BitacoraModel();
$info = $modelo->buscarBitacora();
if(!empty($info)){
  $response = array("response" => true, "bitacoras" => $info;
}else{
  $response = array("response" => false, "message" => "No se encontraron resultadoos");
}
return $response;
}
}
```

Esta vendria siendo la parte del model donde hago el llamado a la base de datos y obtenfo los valores de la bitacora, el cual si me los entrega satisfactoriamente. Ya que ejecuto mi proyecto y se muestra perfectamente, solo me queda ajuntarle la paginacion pero no se donde agregar el comando paginate()

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class BitacoraModel extends Model
 {
 function buscarBitacora(){

$info = DB::select('SELECT *
                      FROM tbl_bitacora 
                      ORDER BY id DESC');

if(count($info) > 0){
  return $info;
}else{
  return array();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo correcto según los estándares de Laravel sería definir el modelo correctamente, y bueno, la búsqueda podrías realizarla de varias formas. Por simplicidad, vamos a hacerlo todo en el controlador, definiendo correctamente el modelo:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class BitacoraModel extends Model
 {
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_bitacora';
 }
```

En el controlador aprovechamos las funcionalidades de Eloquent y aplicamos la paginación:

```
function buscarBitacora(Request $request)
{
    $info = BitacoraModel::orderByDesc('id')->paginate(10);

    if (!empty($info)) {

        return [
            "response" => true, 
            "bitacoras" => $info,
        ];

    } 

    return [
            "response" => false,
            "message" => "No se encontraron resultadoos"
           ];
}
```